# Write a custom aggregate function for Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I want to write an aggregate function that returns a text formatted like: min -> max for an integer column, where
min and max are minimum and maximum values of that column.
For example:

```
SELECT min_to_max(val) FROM (VALUES(5),(3),(6),(7),(9),(10),(7)) t(val);
```

would return

```
min_to_max
-----------
3 -> 10
```

I tried writing using a cursor but I think using a custom aggregate would be much better but I'm clueless how to write a custom aggregate.

What I have done is written a normal function:

```
create or replace function min_to_max()
returns varchar
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
   answer varchar;
begin
   select MIN(val) || '->' ||  max(val)
   into answer
   from abc;

return answer;
end;
$$;
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you try reading the documentation?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I dont understand how the aggregate function works, went through a couple of examples but couldnt figure out how to write it.

Comment: Please post your attempted aggregate function and its output. Post as text - **no images**.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need an aggregate function? MIN() and MAX() work fine:

```
SELECT MIN(val) || '->' ||  max(val) FROM (VALUES(5),(3),(6),(7),(9),(10),(7)) t(val);
```

Comment: Yes I know this works fine, I want to write a custom aggregate function that I can run on a table instead of a select query everytime. I want to learn how to write aggregate functions

Answer (score 0):

As suspected you attempted a standard function, however this is only part of defining an aggregate. User defined aggregate requires basically the definition ([create aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createaggregate.html)) and 2 functions, one function to define the state-to-state transition and one function to handle the production of the final result. ([see demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c1d23f52d5ed42ee85f724c3a6852fde))

```
-- function to manage the state to state transition 
create or replace 
 function uagg_m2m (cagg bigint[], cval int)
   returns bigint[]
  language plpgsql
    strict
as $$
-- SFUNC for min_to_max AGGREGATE
declare nagg bigint[]; 
begin
    nagg[1] = least(cval::bigint, cagg[1]);
    nagg[2] = greatest(cval::bigint, cagg[2]);
    return nagg; 
end;
$$; 

-- function to manaage the final output
create or replace 
 function uagg_m2m_fin (cagg bigint[])
   returns text
  language plpgsql
as $$
--  FINALFUNC for min_to_max AGGREGATE 
declare agg int[] = '{null,null}';
begin
     -- if the low value is = to initialization value 
     -- it means that all values for a state translation were null
     -- in that case then 
     if cagg[1] <> 2147483648 then 
        agg[1] = cagg[1]::int;
        agg[2] = cagg[2]::int;
     end if;
    
     return agg[1] || ' -> ' || agg[2]; 
end;
$$;

-- define user aggregate
create or replace  aggregate  min_to_max (p_val integer)
    (
      sfunc = uagg_m2m                       -- state-to-state transition function  
    , stype = bigint[]                       -- array with 2 elements representing min, max.
    , finalfunc = uagg_m2m_fin               -- final result handling function   
    , initcond = '{2147483648, -2147483649}' -- initial state, array of (min, max) 
    );
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, old unanswered questions is what I was looking for. If the above successfully answered your question that please accept it. This helps future questioners with similar questions and removes the question from the unanswered queue.  Please do not leave successfully answered questions as unanswered.